# Minimal API: the api doesnt load because its too big?

Tags: flutter, asp.net-web-api, postman, minimal-apis

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create minimal API, the JSON I retrieved from MapGet taken too long to load, is the limit for how big can minimal api load?

this is my scheme

```
[
  {
    "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
    "drPi00001": "string",
    "drPi00002": "string",
    "drPi00003": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.792Z",
    "drPi00004": "string",
    "drPi00005": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.792Z",
    "drPi00006": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.792Z",
    "drPi00008": "string",
    "drPi00011": "string",
    "drPi00012": "string",
    "drPi00013": "string",
    "drPi00014": "string",
    "drPi00015": "string",
    "drPi00017": "string",
    "drPi00018": 0,
    "drPi00019": "string",
    "drPi000Ud": "2023-06-13T07:18:32.793Z",
    "drPi000Ub": "string",
    "drPi00022": "string",
    "drPi000Ds": "string",
    "drPi00023": "string",
    "drPi000Id": 0,
    "drPi00007": 0,
    "drPi00009": 0,
    "drPi00020": 0,
    "drPi00021": 0,
    "drPi00016": 0,
    "drPi00010": 0
  }
]
```

and this my MapGet code,its same as example i look into :

```
app.MapGet("/todoitems", async (TestingDbContext db) =>
    await db.DrPi000s.ToListAsync());
```

and this is my builder

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestingDbContext>(opt =>opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase")));
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
        );
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

when i try it on the postman, its takes too long to load the API either,
is there any way to solve, otherwise, how to get only specific attribute in the model?

Comment: There isn't enough information to give a good answer here. Any relatively quick API shouldn't make a big problem. But if postman is taking a long time to retrieve the data as well (that's what it sounds like from your description) this is a server problem, not a flutter problem. You could theoretically make the situtation better by making a loading screen that resembles the loaded screen, but that's an entirely a UX issue.